# Attempting to get the sum of all file line counts in a directory

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to get the number of lines in all files in my directory. I've tried using some kind of variable I set to 0 and looping through all the files and getting their line number.

```
> $i=0;ls | foreach{$i += [int](get-content $_ | measure-object -line)};$i
```

However, every time I try adding it to the variable I set to 0, it shoots out an odd error:

```
Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TextMeasureInfo" value of type
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TextMeasureInfo" to type "System.Int32".
At line:1 char:19
+ $i=0;ls | foreach{$i += [int](get-content $_ | measure-object -line)};$i
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
```

Why does this operation not work and how could it be resolved?
Is there a quicker way of obtaining the number of lines in all files in a directory?

Comment: One liner: in your path (dir | gc | measure-object).Count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the Lines:

```
$i=0;ls -File | foreach{$i += [int](get-content $_ | measure-object -line).Lines};$i
```

I've also added the -File switch to ls/gci to only get the content of files.

Version with aliases expanded:

```
$i=0;Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object {$i += [int](Get-Content $_ | Measure-Object -line).Lines};$i
```

Comment: Thanks for this. ".Count" returns 1, but ".Lines" returns the true number of lines in the file, so I changed it to this: 
$i=0;ls | foreach{$i += (get-content $_ | measure-object -line).lines};$i
which works :)

Comment: Fail on my part, @OrangeReceptacle. Upsdated my example!

Comment: Thanks for the update, I've accepted your answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks, @OrangeReceptacle. My first answer was a little hasty! ;)